# How to generate random matrices with contraints?

Tags: matrix, random

I have a matrix

`mat = {{Sqrt[(1 + a0 + a3)/2], (a1 - I a2)/Sqrt[2 (1 + a0 + a3)]}, {0, Sqrt[(1 + a0 - a3)/2 - (a1^2 + a2^2)/(2 (1 + a0 + a3))]}};`

How can I randomly generate `mat` by choosing   `a0` `a1` `a2` and `a4` randomly subjeceted to condition `a0 + a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 <= 1`?

Comment: It all depends on what distribution you want to draw the random numbers from. Could you please be more explicit on this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(mat = {{Sqrt[(1 + a0 + a3)/2], (a1 - I a2)/Sqrt[2 (1 + a0 + a3)]}, {0, 
     Sqrt[(1 + a0 - a3)/2 - (a1^2 + a2^2)/(2 (1 + a0 + a3))]}});
```

Assuming that `-1 <= a0, a1, a2, a3 <= 1`

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[
   a0 + a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 <= 1 && 
    And @@ Thread[-1 <= {a0, a1, a2, a3} <= 1], {a0, a1, a2, a3}];

SeedRandom[1234];

mat /. Thread[{a0, a1, a2, a3} -> RandomPoint[rgn]]

(* {{0. + 0.0949935 I, -0.460629 - 4.49785 I}, {0, 4.52495}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, Bob. I was expecting different matrix elements every time I run the code.

Comment: Each time you execute the last line `mat /. Thread[{a0, a1, a2, a3} -> RandomPoint[rgn]]` by itself, you will get a different result. If you are also executing  `SeedRandom[1234];` it reinitializes from the same starting point and repeats.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible to do this process as:  Let a1^2+a2^2+a3^2=a^2. Then start with a0=0, a=1 all the way to a0=1, a=0 and find all matrices in this range of parameters? Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Yes, ask a new question and explain in detail what you want.